# Is there a way in SASS to do if string contains or ends with?

Tags: sass

I need an if statement in sass like the so:

```
@each $name, $char in $font-icons {
    @if ($name ends with "-outline") {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not exactly what you were looking for, but I think it's about as close as you can get with Sass.

Using `str-index($string, $substring)` you can find out if `$name` contains `-outline`:

```sass
@each $name, $char in $font-icons {
    @if (str-index($name, '-outline')) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Just wrote a quick Sass function to actually find out if the string ends with another string:

```sass
@function ends-with($string, $find) {
  @if (str-index($string, $find) == (str-length($string) - str-length($find) + 1)) {
    @return true;
  } @else {
    @return false;
  }
}

@each $name, $char in $font-icons {
    @if (ends-with($name, '-outline')) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2:** The function above will return false if `$string` contains `$find` more than once. This function will return true if `$string` truly ends with `$find`:

```sass
@function ends-with($string, $find) {
  @if (str-slice($string, (str-length($string) - str-length($find) + 1)) == $find) {
    @return true;
  } @else {
    @return false;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE #3**: Simplified:

```sass
@function ends-with($string, $find) {
  @return str-length($string) >= str-length($find) && str-slice($string, (str-length($string) - str-length($find) + 1)) == $find;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE#3 throws error if length of $string < length of $find.
I added an answer that resolves this error.

Answer (score 3):

Use this SCSS code:

```
@function str-ends-with($string, $find) {
    @return str-length($string) >= str-length($find) AND str-slice($string, (str-length($string) - str-length($find) + 1)) == $find;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I was just searching for this, I'll add this option: [index](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method). `index($list, $value)` returns an `int` (the 1-based index) or `null` meaning it can be used in a boolean context.

Here's a nice use-case:

```
@mixin flexbox($args:'') {
    @if index($args, 'inline') {
        display: inline-flex;
    } @else {
        display: flex;
    }

    @if index($args, 'bar') == null {
        /* style if 'bar' ISN'T passed */
    }
}

.foo {
    @include flexbox(inline);
}
```

You can create pleasantly sophisticated mixins and for-loops with a single string of space-concatenated keywords instead of maps. (Think of how browsers process `background: red url(image.png) no-repeat center;`)

Answer (score 1):

try this for *contains*:

```
@each $animal in puma, sea-slug, egret, salamander {
  @if (str-index($animal, -slug)) {
    .#{$animal}-icon {
      background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
    }
  }
}
```

and this is for *ends with*:

```
@each $animal in puma, sea-slug, sea-slugs, egret, salamander {
  @if (str-index($animal, -slug) and (str-index($animal, -slug) + 4) == str-length($animal) ) {
    .#{$animal}-icon {
      background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
@each $animal in puma, seaf-slugs, sea-slug, egret, salamander {
  $ind: str-index($animal, -slug);
  @if ($ind and ($ind + 4) == str-length($animal) ) {
    .#{$animal}-icon {
      background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
    }
  }
}
```

note, that *sea-slugs* does not match our `@if`, hard coded "4" is the length of our search criteria (*-slug*) - 1.

you can test your sass at http://www.sassmeister.com/

Answer (score 1):

this is the one way of doing it

```
    @if (str-index($name, "-outline")!=null) {
      #{$name}{
        background-color:$char;
      }
        //do something
    }
}
```

`str-index($name, "-outline")` Returns the first index of $substring(`-outline`) in $string(`$name`), or `null` if `$name` doesn’t contain `-outline`.